# De/Serialization templates

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to de/serialize objects. However, I sometimes I need to serialize them in a way and other times in another way.

Example:

```
 public interface I : ISerializable {

     String X { get; set; }
     String Y { get; set; }

 }

 public class A : I
 {
     String X {...}
     String Y {...}
     String MyZ { ... }
 }

 public class B : I
 {
     String X {...}
     String Y {...}
     String MyS { ... }
 }
```

Sometimes I need to serialize an `A a` or a `B b` object using only `X` field, and other times I only need to serialize `Y` field.

Please, realize this is a slight example. What's really there under the scene is that I want to save a objects only with essential information, and other times I need to save other fields.

It's something like applying serialization templates.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Instead of:

```
var f = new BinaryFormatter();
f.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, new []{ "X", "Y" });
```

Use:

```
var f = new BinaryFormatter();
f.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, TemplatesEnum.Template1);
```

So, each object is resposible for himself in order to serialize itself according to `TemplatesEnum` values.

Comment: take a look at `[XmlIgnore]` attribute

Comment: You need to serialize it how? XML? JSON? Binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to implement `ISerializable` with taking advantage of `StreamingContext`:

```
public enum TemplatesEnum
{
    Template1,
    Template2,
}

[Serializable]
public class A : I
{
    public String X { get; set; }
    public String Y { get; set; }
    public String MyZ { get; set; }

    public A() {}

    // Special ctor for deserialization
    public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // Ignore context while deserializing.

        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
        {
            switch (entry.Name)
            {
                case "X":
                    X = (string)entry.Value;
                    break;

                case "Y":
                    Y = (string)entry.Value;
                    break;

                case "MyZ":
                    MyZ = (string)entry.Value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // ISerializable implementation
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        TemplatesEnum templ = (TemplatesEnum)context.Context;

        // Determin which properties should be serialized depending on the context.
        switch(templ)
        {
            case TemplatesEnum.Template1:
                info.AddValue("X", X);
                break;

            case TemplatesEnum.Template2:
                info.AddValue("X", X);
                info.AddValue("Y", Y);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

(FYI: `nameof(X)` is preferable to the literal `"X"` after C# 6.)

Then set TemplatesEnum param to `IFormatter.Context` when serializing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new A() { X = "foo", Y = "bar", MyZ = "baz" };

        var f = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Serialize depending on a TemplateEnum param.
        f.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, TemplatesEnum.Template1);

        using (var stm = new FileStream("somefile.bin", FileMode.Create))
        {
            f.Serialize(stm, obj);
        }

        // Deserialize
        using (var stm = new FileStream("somefile.bin", FileMode.Open))
        {
            A des = f.Deserialize(stm) as A;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I got I'm able to use a `StreamingContext` object. As far I've been able to guess your approach is `Main` class provides which fields de/serialize, so an external class provides this information. My guessing was running about each class is reponsible for itself. I've edited the post.

Comment: Maybe it's almost the same. Before updating my answer, let me ask you one question. When deserializing, do you need a TemplateEnum param? Or simple deserializing from the serialized data?

Comment: I intended to use a `TemplateEnum` parameter in order set the way each object has to be serialized.

Comment: Updated. I read your comment as you don't want TemplateEnum when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to serialize an object to a file is using the class BinaryFormatter. You should include the attribute [Serializable()] to your class. If you don't want to persist a specific field of your class you can also use [NonSerialized] attribute. You can control also the serialization process using OnSerialized attribute and the other that you see on the example below. There is more than one Formatter that you can use, that depends how you want to save your data, to xml format, to a json format, or to a file with a specific format.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject 
{
  public string n1;
  [NonSerialized] public int n2;
  public String str;

[OnSerializing()]
internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    n1= "This value went into the data file during serialization.";
}

[OnSerialized()]
internal void OnSerializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    n1 = "This value was reset after serialization.";
}

[OnDeserializing()]
internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    n1 = "This value was set during deserialization";
}

[OnDeserialized()]
internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    n1 = "This value was set after deserialization.";
}
}

var obj = new MyObject();
// Open a file and serialize the object into binary format.
Stream stream = File.Open("DataFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
// Deserialize the object from the data file.
obj = (TestSimpleObject)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```